# Load whole project from Eclipse(about source code)

Tags: java, eclipse, load

I am working on buid a plugin of Eclipse. In one step, i load the project through scan classpath,but the feedback from requirement is:

Loading projects encompasses two things:

1. Loading multiple files from the same
   directory/package
2. Including files from other packages through for instance Eclipse's .classpath files

Since the prototype will be built into an Eclipse plugin anyways, is it fine to use Eclipse stuff, like the .classpath files? you are now loading and reading these files yourself. It might be more convenient to use Eclipse code for this, since it has to be already there.

I have no idea how to deal with it from Eclipse, can anybody help?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Your question is somewhat vague. Are you trying to build an Eclipse plugin to scan all files and "related" files from an Eclipse project? If so, my guess is that this has been done before.

Comment: This plugin is used for proofing work. So it need to load these work through eclipse. I am looking for whether Eclipse has a nice API for its plugins to do such stuff, loading files.

Comment: I think this moment i need to know how the EC implements importing project and which part of the EC'S codes works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for PDE build. You could have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html).

Comment: THX, i will have a look at it.